# Incorrect login from terminal berfore desktop login

Tags: command-line, 20.04

So, I was trying to change my username and had to use the terminal before the login screen. It asked for my username and password to log in. But when I entered my username and password it said incorrect login. I kept using different usernames like the name of the home folder,the name shown on login screen, root but still nothing.

Comment: The username is the one you defined when installing.

Comment: How did you change your username? If this was done incorrectly, then complications may arise ...

Comment: @ChanganAuto I used that one too, Still says incorrect

Comment: @matigo I haven't changed it right now

Comment: If you haven't change it yet then the one you entered is indeed wrong. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I tried it alot of times, I even checked if i'm entering the right username, Like is just straight as my username or myusername@computername

Comment: It's just the username exactly as it appeared when you defined during the installation, a single "word" lowercase characters. Ubuntu tends to use first name by default. So, if you entered your name as "John Smith" during the installation your username, unless otherwise specified, will be "john".